# Rank of a matrix given the eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $A$ is a $n$ by $n$ matrix with eigenvalues $\lambda_1,\lambda_2, \cdots, \lambda_{n-1}$ (all are non zero and may not distinct)  and $0$. Is the rank of $A$ equals $n-1$?please someone help.Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is correct.

In general, the nullity of a matrix is the dimension of the eigenspace associated with $0$ (that is, the number of linearly independent eigenvectors).  The rank of a matrix will be $n$ minus this number.

Comment: Thanks @omn, you are right.